# Can you compile an exe together with a python script?

Tags: python, compilation

I'm trying to make a python script that is controlling and gathering data from an .exe via the system("") command and os lib.

I want to combine both the .exe and python script into one big .exe file.

Is this possible? Or can i make the python script an exe and still run it side by side to the other exe?

Practical info:

- The Python script only executes the .exe and reads the output.
- The program needs access to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine everything into one python script and use subprocess to run and get return value of your exe. You can also run multiprocess to execute multiple subprocess at the same time.

Example:

```
                try:
                    exe = subprocess.run(test.exe,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=1, shell=True)
                    data = exe.stdout.decode().strip()
                except:
                    data = ""
```